# Bcc field missing in getSentMIMEMessage()

Tags: email, phpmailer, mime

I am trying to create MIME message using `phpmailer()`. 
Everything works fine but Bcc field is missing when I read the MIME message.

I am using below technique to create MIME Message.

```
$mail->preSend();
$mime = $mail->getSentMIMEMessage();
```

The MIME message created by the above code is used in some other app to send email.

TO and CC field works fine but Bcc field is missing.

Kindly tell me where I am wrong.

Kindly let me know you are not able to get my question.
Happy to share more info.

Comment: Do you want to save entire message for later sending ?

Answer (score 0):

Er, you do know [what BCC does](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.6.3), don't you? BCC is typically removed by an MTA, otherwise it wouldn't be blind, and PHPMailer is effectively an MTA.

Comment: Thanks Synchro! Got it. Thinking of a work around in my code i.e. to send separate emails who are marked in Bcc as a temporary fix. Can you suggest me any other way?

Answer (score 0):

It's a very old question but I encountered the same problem today. We're using PHPMailer in our software Group-Office and there we want to get the full MIME to save into the sent items folder. I made an override which adds the BCC header back in when calling getSentMimeMessage();

You can view the code here:

https://github.com/Intermesh/groupoffice/commit/a41682671b9658653649c1cfd79688cdcf28b820

```php
    /**
     * Returns the whole MIME message.
     * Includes complete headers and body.
     * Only valid post preSend().
     *
     * @see PHPMailer::preSend()
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSentMIMEMessage()
    {
        $header = $this->MIMEHeader;

        // PHPMailer leaves BCC out of headers when using SMTP. We want this header for our sent items
        // source. So we append it here.
        if (
            (
                'sendmail' !== $this->Mailer && 'qmail' !== $this->Mailer && 'mail' !== $this->Mailer
            )
            && count($this->bcc) > 0
        ) {
            $header .= $this->addrAppend('Bcc', $this->bcc);
        }

        return static::stripTrailingWSP($header . $this->mailHeader) .
            static::$LE . static::$LE . $this->MIMEBody;
    }
```

I hope this helps someone encountering this problem too.

Best regards,
Merijn